# Simple Neural Network does not learn non linear data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to understand why this sample Neural Network with Numpy does not learn non-linear data. Even a simple NN is supposed to learn non-linear data right?

I want my NN to learn that if the input is 1 then 0 if the input is greater than 1 and less than 4 then 1. If value > 4 then 0.
I have tried many sample NN codes with numpy from google, I seem to get this problem.

The below code does not learn, but learn well with input [2,2,0,0] desired [1,1,0,0].

```
import numpy as np

# #sigmoid function
def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

# input dataset
X = np.array([  [1],
                [2],
                [3],
                [4] ])

# #output dataset            
y = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

# #seed random numbers to make calculation
# #deterministic (just a good practice)
np.random.seed(1)

# #initialize weights randomly with mean 0
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((1,1)) - 1

for iter in range(10000):

    # #forward propagation
    l0 = X
    l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0,syn0))

    # #how much did we miss?
    l1_error = y - l1

    # multiply how much we missed by the 
    # slope of the sigmoid at the values in l1
    l1_delta = l1_error * nonlin(l1,True)

    # #update weights
    syn0 += np.dot(l0.T,l1_delta)

print ("Output After Training:")
print (l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your model is essentially a linear model. You need to add at least one hidden layer if you want to fit nonlinear data.

Comment: It's not a linear model, a sigmoid function was used to introduce non-linearity.

Comment: @AbienFredAgarap I hope you will find this helpful: [Why is logistic regression a linear model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88603/why-is-logistic-regression-a-linear-model)

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot that it's a _generalized_ linear model. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you have built a simple linear logistic regression model.

The sigmoid in your NN is only used to get the prediction of your model and not to actually non-linearly train the NN.

A good start at learning neural networks is this: http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/implementing-a-neural-network-from-scratch/